# Reversing an input from a file (C++)

Tags: c++, list

I'm creating a very basic program that reads in a list of numbers from a text file, prints them in reverse order, then states if that order is the same as the original (like a palendrome).

I have the program able to print in reverse order so far, but I'm not sure how detect if it's the same as the original file. Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

EDIT: Sorry, had to go away. Here's what I have so far. Got it to reverse, just need to check for palindrome. Will read over replies.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
const int ARRYLENGTH=20;

int contnums[ARRYLENGTH];
int contents;


ifstream myFile("problem3.txt");
if(! myFile )
{
cout << "File cannot be found";
exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

while(!myFile.eof())
{
myFile>>contents;
    for(int i=0;i<ARRYLENGTH;i++)
    {
    myFile >> contnums[i];
    }
}
cout<<contents<<" ";

for (int i = 1; i < ARRYLENGTH; i++)
{
bool same = false;
for (int j = 0; j < i && (same == false); j++){
if (contnums[i] == contnums[j]) 
same = true;
}
if (!same) {

cout<< contnums[i] << " ";
}
}

cout << "\n";

system("pause");
myFile.close();
}
```

Comment: Show what you have so far, and where you are stuck

Comment: Will get it up here, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just wondered wether comparing 2 lists would work in std library. It works :-)

```
#include <list>
#include <fstream>

using std::list;
using std::ifstream;

bool foo(const char * fn)
{
    list<int> orig;
    list<int> rev;
    ifstream ifs(fn,std::ifstream::in);

    while( ifs.good() && !ifs.eof() )
    {
        int num =0;
        ifs >> num;
        orig.push_back(num);
        rev.push_front(num);
    }
    bool equal = (orig == rev);
    return equal;
}

static bool test1 = foo("file1.txt");
static bool test2 = foo("file2.txt");
```

**WHERE**

file1.txt contains

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 8
```

and file2.txt contains

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
```

Comment: +1, but you don't need two lists. [`equal(orig.begin(), orig.end(), orig.rbegin())`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal) will work just fine. Also: std::vector is almost always faster than std::list.

Comment: I'd just continue with @Kay, reading the file in by an iterator pair constructor. It's a lot shorter and safer than that loop.

Comment: @Kay thanks! I din't know std::equal (or forgot it) Last years I use C++ with Qt.

Answer (score 0):

Try iterating from begin to end and comparing the values with values of an iterator from end to begin.

Comment: Exactly, rbegin is the end, isn't it.

Comment: `bool palindrome = std::equal(s.begin(), s.begin() + s.size()/2, s.rbegin())`

Comment: @jussi, Forgive me if I'm wrong, but I believe some things with rbegin/rend will work where end/begin won't, particularly with supporting `operator++`, but not `operator--`.

Comment: @jussi Compare it with a normal array: [0,1,2,3]. begin() points to 0, end() points after 3, rbegin() points to 3, rend() points before 0. So begin()/rbegin() and end()/rend() are swapped and one off.

Answer (score 0):

If you know how many items you have it could simple be done by:

```
for(int i = 0; i < count/2; ++i) { //count/2 becouse you only have to check half
   if(array[i] != array[count-i-1]) { /*not palindrome */ }
}
//palindrome
```

Simplest way, but i like @Dave's from comment one better since it ueses STL and iterators in nice way. (As long as you are working on STL container).